# Telegram Quiz Bot with pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

Trying to build a Telegram Quiz Bot using pyTelegramBotAPI. I'm using sched to schedule the message Handler but i don't know how to stop the Message Handler and return to my Main Script which will scheudle the next Round.

Tryed to use timeout but it is not working!

My Code:

```
import telebot
import sched, time

def listen():
    print("Send my your Answer")
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
    def command_default(m):
        print(m.text)
    bot.polling()



API_TOKEN = 'xxxx'

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

s.enter(50, 1, listen)
s.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

In this use case you have to use something called a [Finite State Machine (FSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). You keep track of user states, such as one where the user is ready to send an answer.

This is already implemented in pyTelegramBotAPI, with the [next_step_handler()](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py). However, I suggest you instead create your own solution, as the one provided by the wrapper is quite buggy.

Here is an example (you can translate the page): https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter11.html